# Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive: Accesing the data in the disk?

Tags: networking, mount, data-recovery, nas

I have an Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive, 1TB, and lately I can't access the data on the drive. The shares (both built-in and created by me) are there, the security works, but when trying to access the data I get a "The network path was not found" message which is worrying, to say the least.

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the data off the disks somehow, as some of the data in the drive (ie, pictures and videos of my 1.5 yrs old son) is hard if not impossible to find otherwise.

Thanks a lot

Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved:

I mounted the drive in a different PC, using Knoppix.

The Data partition (996 MB) is XFS, and it didn't mount properly, but the mount messages suggested using some new "xfs_*" command that validated the config - it said I might lose data, etc but it run very quickly and all the data was there.

Once I could mount it, I copied it somewhere else and am looking for a 2 drive NAS ATM :))